# Arabic words don't display correctly (showing left to right order)

Tags: python, debian, arabic

Showing the same Json format data, 
Arabic words display correctly (right to left) in Windows Python 3.6.4 Shell,
but don't display correctly in Debian Python 3.5.3

Would love to know what's wrong with Debian, and how to fix it.

additional information:

I use python shell IDLE graphically from X.Org X Server 1.19.2
my locale configuration settings:
C. UTF-8
ar-AE
ar-AE. UTF-8
en_GB. UTF-8
en_US. UTF-8
ko_KR. UTF-8

I tried to write Arabic characters in terminal, 
it goes from left to right order too.

Here's captured images from Debian and Windows, respectively:

[image: Debian python shell]

[image: Windows python shell]

[I have a problem writing Arabic characters on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRMSz.png)

Comment: Which graphical environment are you using on Debian? This is probably more related to the GUI (I'm guessing Gnome) and its configuration, than anything specifically about Python or even generally programming-related.

Comment: If you exit Python and do something at the bash prompt which involves an Arabic string, does that display correctly? For example, does `echo 'الحاسوب'` display correctly?

Comment: Thank you very much!
Now, I'm trying to install Arabic keyboard in Debian.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more details. Are you running IDLE graphically or from the terminal? Which graphical environment (Gnome? Which version?) and how is its internationalization / locale configuration set up?

Comment: to tripleee, I just updated information which you required.
Thank you very much always.

Comment: Could you also check(click) a image file named: I have a problem writing Arabic characters on terminal too?